# Using cypress to read the dom and create an array data structure for each of the rows

Tags: cypress

Please take a look this image. Want to know how could I do this using cypress?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? What does the actual DOM look like, and what's the expected output?

Comment: Hi @ jonrsharpe,  Can you please take a look below comment?

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe I am expecting something like this cy.log(content)) should return me array structure like [23,50,63,90,10,30,155,23,18]

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this depending on what exactly are you looking for:

```
cy.get('table')
  .find('tbody tr')
  .then(trs => {
    const content = [];
    Cypress.$(trs).each((_, tr) => {
      const row = [];
      const tds = Cypress.$(tr).find('td');
      Cypress.$(tds).each((_, td) => {
        const text = Cypress.$(td)
          .contents()
          .last()
          .text();
        row.push(text);
      });
      content.push(row);
    });

    console.log(content);
  });
```

Comment: let solution = (x, n = x.length) => {
    if(x.length === 1){
           return x[0];
    }
         let leftSum = 0, rightSum = 0;
         for(let i = 1; i < n; i++){
              rightSum += x[i];
         }
                for(let i = 0, j = 1; j < n; i++, j++){
                   rightSum -= x[j];
                   leftSum += x[i];
                      if(rightSum === leftSum){
                         return x[i+1];
                      }
                }
                return -1;
           }
           //cy.log(solution([23,50,63,90,10,30,155,23,18]));

Comment: Hi @martin, How could I enter   something like this using solution function cy.log(solution([23,50,63,90,10,30,155,23,18])); which will give me 10

Comment: Hi @martin I have use your code and pass something like this cy.log(solution(content)) give me -1 why? I would expect 10 instead of -1